php value errors in Zabbix setup
I've installed Zabbix 7 on Debian Bookworm. PHP 8.2
Getting the following errors during config
  Minimum required size of PHP post is 16M (configuration option "post_max_size").
  Minimum required limit on execution time of PHP scripts is 300 (configuration option "max_execution_time").
  Minimum required limit on input parse time for PHP scripts is 300 (configuration option "max_input_time").

I've updated
apache2/php.ini
fpm/php.ini
cli/php.ini

and restarted zabbix and apache but still get the same issue.
What have I missed?

wild guess: you're configuring a different PHP than zabbix is running on.

Great thought but Zabbix is reporting 8.2 which is the one I've changed.

not really! It's the right version, but is it actually the right php? and not some PHP running in a prefix or being configured to look somewhere else for configuration files? Did you also restart apache, assuming this is mod_php territory?

(also, just realized: these might be manual overrides that get set via some non-config-file mechanism; the warning message telling you the configuration file clause doesn't mean it was caused by a configuration file!)

Yeah, apache was restarted. Def running 8.2 as I had a problem related to it on a website.  I'll search for other files containing the value.

OK, changed all the versions of php.ini
Searched systemwide all .ini, .cfg and .conf files for post_max_size and no others found.

Implement a php status page as described at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php to check your current configuration settings.

Well, I put some debug in the zabbix code and it's using /etc/php/8.2/fpm/php.ini
Which has a value of 16M.....
I can't believe that's a bug as someone else would have spotted it, but I think I'll look for another solution!
Thanks for your suggestion.
